# Use SerCx.h in Windows Driver?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kmdf, wdf

I'm working on a Windows KMDF driver using VS2019, where I need to use the SerCx2 framework.
Although, if I use #include <sercx.h> I get "No such file or directory".
If I use #include <sercx/2.0/sercx.h> the compiler finds the header file, but instead there are linking errors:

> Error LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  KMDF
> Driver1   C:\Users\dev\source\repos\KMDF
> Driver1\x64\Debug\KMDFDriver1.sys 1    Error  LNK2001 unresolved external
> symbol SercxDriverGlobals KMDF Driver1    C:\Users\dev\source\repos\KMDF
> Driver1\KMDF Driver1\Driver.obj   1    Error  LNK2001 unresolved external
> symbol SercxFunctions KMDF Driver1    C:\Users\dev\source\repos\KMDF
> Driver1\KMDF Driver1\Driver.obj   1

I have tried manually adding the folder containing sercxstubs.lib as an additional library directory in linker settings, but that makes no difference.

Anyone here who has worked with SerCx2 and has an idea what might be the issue?
It seems as there should be somewhere in the settings to configure SerCx (for example, choose between version 1 and 2). But I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Just the directory is not enough, you have to explicitly name sercxstubs.lib in the Additional Dependencies linker settings.